# SQL (mysql) - If a given row on a given column as a certain value, don't list that column

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that retrieves some data, among those data I have some that are returned with a value like 0. I would like the query to NOT return the columns when that's the case.

How can we do such a thing?

Regards,
MEM

Comment: We will have always only one record returned. So, let's say we have several columns for that record and on one of these columns we have the value of 0.00. If that's the case, exclude that column from the listing.

Answer (score 1):

select `<column_name>` from `<table_name>` where `<column_name>` <> 0.0

Here is all the data in a sample database. Notice how there are 3 rows with one having a zero value for the `num` column.

```
mysql> select * from test_tbl;

     +------+----------+
     | num  | some_str |
     +------+----------+
     |    0 | matt     |
     |    2 | todd     |
     |    3 | Paul     |
     +------+----------+
     3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now lets use the where clause to specify the rows we want to ignore (it's a little bit of reverse logic because we are actually specifying what rows we want).

```
mysql> select * from test_tbl where num <> 0.0;
     +------+----------+
     | num  | some_str |
     +------+----------+
     |    2 | todd     |
     |    3 | Paul     |
     +------+----------+
     2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Note**: This will only work without getting messy if 0 is the only value you are worried about. A better way would be to allow nulls in your column and then you can check to see if they are non-null in the where clause.